# How to handle the termination request sent by taskkill in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, terminate, win32-process, taskkill

In Windows, when you run the command `taskkill program.exe` (without `/F`), `program.exe` is sent some kind of signal that request it to terminate normally.

I've checked that this is in fact true with the programs `notepad.exe`, `mspaint.exe` and `wordpad.exe`.
They all show the close confirmation dialog when they are "taskkilled".

What condition/message/signal do I have to handle in my program to respond to the termination request sent by the `taskkill` command?

---

PS: I'm already handling `WM_QUIT` and `WM_CLOSE` messages.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *handle*? What are you trying to do specifically in response?

Comment: taskkill sends `WM_CLOSE` to the application's top-level windows.

Comment: Probably like this: [How To Terminate an Application "Cleanly" in Win32](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/178893/how-to-terminate-an-application-cleanly-in-win32)

Comment: @eryksun, in my program I have one message-only window. I don't have actual visible windows. Does that mean that `taskkill` will not work with my program?

Comment: I just checked. taskkill sends `WM_CLOSE` to a hidden window. But the GUI task manager requires a visible window for this.

Comment: A message-only window cannot get a WM_CLOSE message, it is invisible to external processes.  So you get the only other thing that taskkill can do, it calls TerminateProcess().  Bam, no signal.  If you need a notification then don't make it message-only.

Comment: @eryksun, as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171218-00/?p=97595), message-only windows are not top windows. That may explain why `taskkill` is not working with my program.

Comment: Which Windows version? I just tried this in Windows 10 with a hidden window with `HWND_MESSAGE` as the parent, and `taskkill /pid [pid]` sent it `WM_CLOSE`.

Comment: @eryksun, I tried on Windows 7 and Vista.

Comment: Just checked in the debugger. It's working because taskkill (at least in Windows 10) has an an `EnumMessageWindows` function that calls `FindWindowEx` to find message-only windows.

Comment: This is not true: "A message-only window cannot get a WM_CLOSE message, it is invisible to external processes." Message-only windows don't get broadcast messages because technically they are child windows. But of course `WM_CLOSE` can be sent to them. and of course they're "visible to external processes" in the sense that they can be enumerated via `FindWindowEx`.